# Can a GenServer Have Its Own Struct in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, gen-server

**Scenario:**

- I have a simple **`GenServer`** for managing some state.
- Currently, I am using **`map` to manage my state**. But it is growing as
  I am adding more data to the state.

**Problem:**

- So, to have some compile-time guarantee, can I have a `struct` in my `GenServer` module?
- And, if yes, is it a right approach?
- If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just declare a normal struct (optionally in a module nested in your `GenServer` namespace) and use it as an initial state:

```rb
defmodule Test do
  defmodule State do
    defstruct ~w|foo bar baz|a
  end

  use GenServer

  def start_link(opts \\ []) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %State{foo: 42, bar: opts}, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  @impl true
  def init(opts \\ []), do: {:ok, opts}

  def state, do: GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :state)

  @impl true
  def handle_call(:state, _from, %State{} = state) do
    {:reply, state, state}
  end
end

with {:ok, _} <- Test.start_link(pi: 3.14) do
  IO.inspect Test.state, label: "State"
end
#⇒ State: %Test.State{bar: [pi: 3.14], baz: nil, foo: 42}
```